# UIButton image in UITableViewCell keeps being overridden from XIB file

Tags: xcode, image, button, uitableview

We have a Masterview where project data are shown. Each row is build from a Custom UITableViewCell with a XIB file. There is a button on each Cell.
We use the Button to explode cq. implode the project list (based on a hierarchy).
When doing so the image on the button needs to be changed.
This works fine when a button is clicked (a variable:show for all the projects is turned on/off depending on the collapse cq. explode situation, only projects are fetched where show = true) and the correct image is shown in every row.

Problem: but when one row is tapped or let's say: selected, then the image from the XIB file is reloaded.

In RootViewController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //  Deselect the currently selected row according to the HIG
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    // Set the detail item in the detail view controller.
    ProjEntity *selectedObject = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self selectProjEntity:selectedObject];

    ProjectTableViewCell *selectedCell = (ProjectTableViewCell *)[[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [selectedCell setCollapseImage:selectedObject];

    [tableView reloadData];
    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

In Cell: ProjectTableViewCell:

```
- (void) setCollapseImage:(ProjEntity *) projRow
{
    UIImage* btImage;

    if ([projRow.explode intValue] == 0)
    {
        if ([projRow.projLevel intValue] == 1)
        {
            btImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"add-big.png"]; 
        }
        else
        {
            btImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"plus.gif"];
        }
    }
    else
    {    
        if ([projRow.projLevel intValue] == 1)
        {
            btImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Minus_groenGroot.png"]; 
        }
        else
        {
            btImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"min.gif"];
        }
     }

    self.collapseButton.imageView.image = btImage;
}
```

So only when a row is selected the button's image does not update.

Comment: Do you set the image in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method as well?